# How to find the difference between two times when times after midnight but still early morning are the next day

Tags: r, time

I am trying to find the difference between the times people wake up and go to sleep from survey data. When I convert the data to a time so that I can use difftime, R doesn't recognise that values after 00:00 are from the next day.

Here is a sample of the data.

```
df <- data.frame(
 b = c('07:00', '10:00', '11:00', '13:00', '05:00'),
 d = c('00:00', '00:30', '23:00', '22:00','04:20')
)
```

I have converted the characters to date times like so

```
 df$b <- strptime(df$b, format = "%H:%M")
 df$d <- strptime(df$d, format = "%H:%M")
```

but then I get stuck

Everything I have tried hasn't worked at all

Comment: Can you share reproducible data and  what you have tried so far

Comment: edited for clarity @user16087142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operator `%%`

```
as.numeric(df$b - df$d) %% (24 * 60)
# [1] 420 570 720 900  40
```

This code assumes that a person sleeps less than 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

When the time difference is negative, add 1440 minutes (24 hours) to get the intended time difference.

```
df$Sleep <- ifelse(df$Waking.up.time - df$Bed.tim >= 0,
                   df$Waking.up.time - df$Bed.tim,
                   df$Waking.up.time - df$Bed.tim + 1440)

df$Sleep
#> [1] 420 570 720 900  40
```

Edit: See Julien's answer for a more elegant solution.